# After Search in SQL Update a column value in the found rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB table where a Field can have several different values, I want to update a field with certain values please see table below

```
ID  Name1   Place   Number
1   Key     TR       3
2   Lock    BG       45
3   Turn    GH       67
4   Key     KL       89
```

I would like to change the Name1 fields containing Key with Keys2. My actual table has more than 100 rows so I don't want to just look for the ID and then replace it.

The search part is not a problem I can do that as follows:

```
Search * tableX where 'Name1' = 'Key'
```

So this would find the rows with ID 1 and 4. The I would like to update these found rows so the table now looks like

```
ID  Name1   Place   Number
1   Key2    TR      3
2   Lock    BG      45
3   Turn    GH      67
4   Key2    KL      89
```

I would not know where to start to update all of found rows. any help is welcome

Comment: @ZaynulAbabinTuhin Are you sure that edit was sensible. I think it changed the question completely when you tabulated the original table. I think `key TR` were supposed to be in the `Name1` column. That was the OP issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly see his output table

Comment: Cannot see a good reason for the numbers not being in the `Number` column. I think we need some clarification here from the OP

Comment: Number need to be in the number column, sorry if I was not clear enough, Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you use `update`:

```
update t
    set Name1 = 'Key2'
    where Name1 = 'Key';
```

Is there something that I'm missing in your question?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thank you so much that was a quick and simple solution, but worked perfect